# Deleting a node from singly linked list has the error "cannot move out of borrowed content"

Tags: linked-list, rust, singly-linked-list

I am making a singly-linked list. When you delete a node, the previous node's `next` should become the current node's `next` (`prev->next = curr->next;`) and return `data` if the index matches. Otherwise, the previous node becomes the current node and the current node becomes the next node (`prev = curr; curr = curr->next;`):

```
struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl LinkedList<i64> {
    fn remove(&mut self, index: usize) -> i64 {
        if self.len() == 0 {
            panic!("LinkedList is empty!");
        }
        if index >= self.len() {
            panic!("Index out of range: {}", index);
        }
        let mut count = 0;
        let mut head = &self.head;
        let mut prev: Option<Box<Node<i64>>> = None;
        loop {
            match head {
                None => {
                    panic!("LinkedList is empty!");
                }
                Some(c) => {
                    // I have borrowed here
                    if count == index {
                        match prev {
                            Some(ref p) => {
                                p.next = c.next;
                                //       ^ cannot move out of borrowed content
                            }
                            _ => continue,
                        }
                        return c.data;
                    } else {
                        count += 1;
                        head = &c.next;
                        prev = Some(*c);
                        //          ^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to field `p.next` of immutable binding
  --> src/main.rs:31:33
   |
30 |                             Some(ref p) => {
   |                                  ----- consider changing this to `ref mut p`
31 |                                 p.next = c.next;
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot mutably borrow field of immutable binding

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:31:42
   |
31 |                                 p.next = c.next;
   |                                          ^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:40:37
   |
40 |                         prev = Some(*c);
   |                                     ^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a33d0e58040dfe071feed4389d382076&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) for more info.

How can I do this? Is my approach wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `impl LinkedList<i64>` instead of `T`?

Comment: Even better: provide a playground link to play with for us :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653148/singly-linked-list-in-rust

Comment: Also please see: http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/ to get some inspiration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singly-Linked List in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653148/singly-linked-list-in-rust)

Comment: I don't think "Singly-Linked List in Rust" is the best duplicate because it doesn't cover OPs error message. There are plenty of other questions that *do* explain that error though...

Comment: I am pretty sure it isn't a duplicate.
As for @Shepmaster, I couldn't find an answer which helps me solve the borrow problem when used in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start, go read [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/). People think that linked lists are *easy* because they've been taught them in languages that either don't care if you introduce memory unsafety or completely take away that agency from the programmer.

Rust does neither, which means that you have to think about things you might never have thought of before.

---

There are a number of issues with your code. The one that you ask about, "cannot move out of borrowed content" is already well-covered by numerous other questions, so there's no reason to restate all those good answers:

- [Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423)
- [Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28258548/155423)
- [error[E0507]: Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43997415/155423)

TL;DR: You are attempting to move ownership of `next` from out of a reference; you cannot.

> ```
> p.next = c.next;
> ```

You are attempting to modify an immutable reference:

> ```
> let mut head = &self.head;
> ```

You allow for people to remove one **past** the end, which doesn't make sense to me:

> ```
> if index >= self.len()
> ```

You iterate the *entire tree* not once, but **twice** before iterating it again to perform the removal:

> ```
> if self.len() == 0
> if index >= self.len()
> ```

---

All of that pales in comparison to the fact that your algorithm is flawed in the eyes of Rust because you attempt to introduce *mutable aliasing*. If your code were able to compile, you'd have a mutable reference to `previous` as well as a mutable reference to `current`. However, you can get a mutable reference to `current` from `previous`. This would allow you to break Rust's memory safety guarantees!

Instead, you can only keep track of `current` and, when the right index is found, break it apart and move the pieces:

```
fn remove(&mut self, index: usize) -> T {
    self.remove_x(index)
        .unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("index {} out of range", index))
}

fn remove_x(&mut self, mut index: usize) -> Option<T> {
    let mut head = &mut self.head;

    while index > 0 {
        head = match { head }.as_mut() {
            Some(n) => &mut n.next,
            None => return None,
        };
        index -= 1;
    }

    match head.take().map(|x| *x) {
        Some(Node { data, next }) => {
            *head = next;
            Some(data)
        }
        None => None,
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423)
- [How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42264041/155423)

---

> [Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a33d0e58040dfe071feed4389d382076&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) for more info.

There are numerous problems with the rest of your code, such as the fact that the result of your `insert` method is unlike any I've ever seen before.

[How I'd write it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7a8fe43dae182a166a2357a231f3a4cc&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).