# How to remove a node from a binary search tree without unsafe?

Tags: rust, binary-tree, borrowing

I am trying to implement a binary search tree in Rust. The remove method uses unsafe Rust code and I want to write the equivalent safe Rust code.

I am having problems as self is a mutable reference and when destructuring it using match statement, the compiler complains because I cannot reassign to it as it is already borrowed.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T: Ord> {
    key: T,
    left: Tree<T>,
    right: Tree<T>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree<T: Ord>(Option<Box<Node<T>>>);

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BinarySearchTree<T: Ord> {
    root: Tree<T>,
}

impl<T: Ord> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Node {
            key: value,
            left: Tree(None),
            right: Tree(None),
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> Tree<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, value: T) {
        let mut current = self;

        while let Some(ref mut node) = current.0 {
            match node.key.cmp(&value) {
                Ordering::Less => current = &mut node.right,
                Ordering::Greater => current = &mut node.left,
                Ordering::Equal => current = &mut node.right,
            }
        }

        current.0 = Some(Box::new(Node::new(value)));
    }

    fn successor(&self, value: &T) -> Option<&T> {
        let mut current = self.0.as_ref();
        let mut successor = None;
        while current.is_some() {
            let node = current.unwrap();
            if *value < node.key {
                successor = current;
                current = node.left.0.as_ref();
            } else {
                current = node.right.0.as_ref();
            }
        }

        successor.map(|node| &node.key)
    }

    fn extract_min(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut node = None;

        if self.0.is_some() {
            let mut current = self;

            while current.0.as_ref().unwrap().left.0.is_some() {
                current = &mut current.0.as_mut().unwrap().left;
            }

            let temp = current.0.take().unwrap();
            node = Some(temp.key);
            current.0 = temp.right.0;
        }

        node
    }

    fn extract_max(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut node = None;

        if self.0.is_some() {
            let mut current = self;

            while current.0.as_ref().unwrap().right.0.is_some() {
                current = &mut current.0.as_mut().unwrap().right;
            }

            let temp = current.0.take().unwrap();
            node = Some(temp.key);
            current.0 = temp.left.0;
        }

        node
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, value: &T) {
        let mut current: *mut Tree<T> = self;

        unsafe {
            while let Some(ref mut node) = (*current).0 {
                match node.key.cmp(value) {
                    Ordering::Less => current = &mut node.right,
                    Ordering::Greater => current = &mut node.left,
                    Ordering::Equal => match (node.left.0.as_mut(), node.right.0.as_mut()) {
                        (None, None) => (*current).0 = None,
                        (Some(_), None) => (*current).0 = node.left.0.take(),
                        (None, Some(_)) => (*current).0 = node.right.0.take(),
                        (Some(_), Some(_)) => {
                            (*current).0.as_mut().unwrap().key = node.right.extract_min().unwrap();
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> BinarySearchTree<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        BinarySearchTree { root: Tree(None) }
    }
    pub fn add(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.root.add(value);
    }
    pub fn remove(&mut self, value: &T) {
        self.root.remove(value);
    }
    pub fn successor(&self, value: &T) -> Option<&T> {
        self.root.successor(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: So after reading the article, I have to come to an understanding that this isn't possible in safe rust. To solve this, I have to use either unsafe rust or a memory arena allocator. Am I correct?

Comment: This question (with small changes) has been [cross-posted to users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/binary-search-tree-node-removal-without-unsafe-code/56078).

Comment: [How to remove the Nth node from the end of a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53242052/3650362) is similar in that it involves removing a node from the middle of a graph (a linked list). I think it should be possible to adapt the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved by steffahn on [users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/binary-search-tree-node-removal-without-unsafe-code/56078/8):

```
fn remove(&mut self, value: &T) {
    let mut current = self;

    while let Some(ref mut node) = current.0 {
        match node.key.cmp(value) {
            Ordering::Less => current = &mut current.0.as_mut().unwrap().right,
            Ordering::Greater => current = &mut current.0.as_mut().unwrap().left,
            Ordering::Equal => match (node.left.0.as_mut(), node.right.0.as_mut()) {
                (None, None) => current.0 = None,
                (Some(_), None) => current.0 = node.left.0.take(),
                (None, Some(_)) => current.0 = node.right.0.take(),
                (Some(_), Some(_)) => {
                    current.0.as_mut().unwrap().key = node.right.extract_min().unwrap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the author,

> the most significant change was re-tracing the path to `node` on the `Less` and `Greater` branches (using `unwrap` , etc). This is probably zero overhead with compiler optimizations.