# Why can't I move out of index of Vec<Rc<dyn T>>?

Tags: rust

First of all, I am sorry for that I cannot compare some duplicate questions to mine because I am a beginner in Rust.
[Possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997415/errore0507-cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content)

The compiler outputs an error for my code as:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<std::rc::Rc<dyn T>>`
  --> src/lib.rs:30:18
   |
30 |     let V_last = data.V[V_lastIdx];
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  move occurs because value has type `std::rc::Rc<dyn T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                  help: consider borrowing here: `&data.V[V_lastIdx]`
```

Please help me to solve problem.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait T {
    fn main(&self, data: &mut Data) -> ();
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct S1 {
    val: usize,
    t: Rc<dyn T>,
}

struct S2 {
    val: usize,
}

impl T for S1 {
    fn main(&self, data: &mut Data) -> () {
        data.V.push(Rc::new(S2 { val: 123 }));
    }
}

impl T for S2 {
    fn main(&self, data: &mut Data) -> () {}
}

struct Data {
    // Up to 1 instance which may hold about 30MB at most.
    V: Vec<Rc<dyn T>>,
    name_match: HashMap<String, (usize, usize)>,
}

fn round(data: &mut Data) {
    let V_lastIdx = data.V.len() - 1;
    let V_last = data.V[V_lastIdx];
    return V_last.main(data);
}
```

After I followed the compiler suggestion, a new error says as follows.

```
 help: consider borrowing here: `&data.V[V_lastIdx]`
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*data` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:34:11
let V_last= &data.V[V_lastIdx];   
   |                 ------ immutable borrow occurs here
34 |    return V_last.main(data);
   |           ^^^^^^^----^^^^^^
   |           |      |
   |           |      immutable borrow later used by call
   |           mutable borrow occurs here
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df2e64f861bb9a306cd69f24d877e316)

> Now I have selected the answer, I notice that my original code could be more simple as following link, with the solution code borrowed from the selected answer.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7258102d51e839a6188d120396473ffa)

Comment: read the compile error, do what it already tell you, then [edit] your question then close it as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017747/why-does-refactoring-by-extracting-a-method-trigger-a-borrow-checker-error/57018038#57018038

Comment: @Stargateur, Please explain how they are duplicate.

Comment: @Stargateur, Can't you see that if the two are really so duplicate, my question is more valuable because my question is clearly shorter and simpler than your link. your link contains too many information and complicated.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the compiler's message suggests that you do?

Comment: fwiw, stargateur's link does a good job of explaining why the compiler's suggestion doesn't work (addressing `fn func(&mut Parent, &Child)`-type patterns), though I agree the Q&A is not particularly easy for a newcomer to understand and apply, since the suggested fix is pretty specific and not the only workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `some_vec[index]`, it will try to *move* the element out of the vec, but [that is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904864/what-does-cannot-move-out-of-index-of-mean). One fix, as provided by the compiler, is to *borrow* the element instead: `&some_vec[index]`. However, the compiler rejects that solution, as well it should, because if allowed the call to `main` with `self` as a reference to an element in `data` would/could be invalidated by the `.push` call.

Another fix, as demonstrated in your self-answer, is require *cloning* the vec `V` so that they have different ownership and therefore the references can't be invalidated.

A better solution is to clone the element and not the whole vector. A particularly reasonable solution given that your elements are `Rc`s and therefore cheap to clone:

```
fn round(data: &mut Data) {
    let V_lastIdx = data.V.len() - 1;
    let V_last = data.V[V_lastIdx].clone();
                               // ^^^^^^^^
    return V_last.main(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Reading the accepted answer, I realized that my solution below was not a good idea at all for my purpose.

I solved the error myself as follows by editing the `round` function.

Before:

```
fn round(data: &mut Data) {
   let V_lastIdx = data.V.len() - 1;
   let V_last= &data.V[V_lastIdx];   
   V_last.main(data)
}
```

After:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9b7fade488635a9b30dfbf97fec8ea8)

```
fn round(V: Vec<Rc<T>>, data: &mut Data) {
   let V_lastIdx = V.len() - 1;
   let V_last = &V[V_lastIdx];   
   V_last.main(data)
}
```